# Multiple dispatch for return values

Tags: julia, multiple-dispatch

I have a routine that can return an array of any FloatingPoint type (or really any numeric type but it's intended for floating points). It computes the convergents of a continued fraction. My problem is that I want the compiler to optimize it for each return type, e.g. Float64, BigFloat, etc. rather than using generic code.

```
function floatconvergents(a::Vector{Int}, n_quotients::Int, t::Type)
    r = Array(t, n_quotients)
    u = Array(t, n_quotients)
    v = Array(t, n_quotients)
    r[1],u[1],v[1] = a[1],0,1
    for k=2:n_quotients
        u[k] = 1 / (a[k] + u[k-1])
        r[k] = (a[k]*r[k-1] + v[k-1]) * u[k]
        v[k] = r[k-1] * u[k]
    end
    return r
end
```

The only solution that seems feasible to me is to pass the result array as an argument and make it a parametric function

```
function floatconvergents!{T<:FloatingPoint}(a::Vector{Int}, n_quotients::Int, r::Vector{T})
```

The only problem I see with this is that there's no reason for supplying the result array as an argument except to specify its type. It just doesn't seem like the "right" thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will dispatch on the type, thus it will specialize the code:

```
function floatconvergents{T<:FloatingPoint}(a::Vector{Int}, n_quotients::Int, ::Type{T})
    r = Array(T, n_quotients)
    u = Array(T, n_quotients)
    v = Array(T, n_quotients)
    r[1],u[1],v[1] = a[1],0,1
    for k=2:n_quotients
        u[k] = 1 / (a[k] + u[k-1])
        r[k] = (a[k]*r[k-1] + v[k-1]) * u[k]
        v[k] = r[k-1] * u[k]
    end
    return r
end
```

It can be called, for example, by `floatconvergents(some_vector, some_int, Float64)`.

Proof:

```
julia> f{T<:FloatingPoint}(::Type{T}) = T===Float64 ? 1 : 0
julia> code_llvm(f, (Type{Float64},))
define i64 @julia_f15644(%jl_value_t*) {
top:
  ret i64 1, !dbg !2042
}
julia> code_llvm(f, (Type{BigFloat},))
define i64 @julia_f15645(%jl_value_t*) {
top:
  ret i64 0, !dbg !2045
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @cristavao-d-sousa ! I haven't seen the `::Type{T}` syntax before. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is called a singleton type. Beware that you can call your function using floatconvergents(v, n, Float64), i.e., you do not need to explicit use Type{Float64} as argument. More about this at http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#singleton-types